# Does it make sense to use two factor authentication with password protected wp-admin folder?

Tags: passwords, authentication, wordpress

I've finished building my wordpress website and now, I'm concerned about the security of the website.

To improve security, I'm using Google two factor authentication plugin while also password-protecting the wp-admin folder besides the default username-password login of wordpress.

My question is, does it make sense to apply all these layers of security? Am I being silly about this? I mean, if either two of these protection methods are used, instead of three, and it is enough, then using all three will be too much of a hassle without bringing significant improvement in security. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what three factors you are counting here.

I count two: (1) passwords (2) Google 2-factor.

Now, I'm not getting into Google's solution, how it works or whether it is good or not.

But simply adding another password, does NOT create a 2nd factor - to do that, you need a *different* factor.

As a reminder, the typical authentication factors are:

1. Something you **know** (e.g. passwords)
2. Something you **have** (e.g. smartcard, or G2F)
3. Something you **are**  (e.g. biometrics).

So having two different passwords is still just one factor, and does not give you the benefits of having the 2nd factor, or prevent the threats against single-factor authn.

Is it silly to add a 2nd factor, given that you already have 2 passwords?
It's hard for us to say, not knowing what the site is for or about, your risk profile, tolerance, etc. But if you need to keep it secure - and it's not your sister's cat's blog - then no, it is not silly at all.

Comment: Thanks AviD. I'll consider your input and think about this further.